# Check for non-UTF8 characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, utf-8

Quick question here, what would be the best way to write a function that would take in a string in Javascript, and return true if it contained no non-UTF8 characters, and false otherwise? I'm not looking for any character to get replaced, I just want to know if the inputted string contains a non-UTF8 character (and then proceeded to warn the user via a popup window or some other form validation). Hopefully this isn't a repost... Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Javascript strings are composed of Unicode characters. All Unicode characters are encodable in UTF-8. Therefore, by definition, a string in Javascript cannot contain any "non-UTF8 characters".

Comment: So what if this string came from a HTML form (textbox)? Basically, I want to ensure that the user doesn't input a character that is non UTF-8 in the textbox (sorry for the confusing wording...)

Comment: Unicode covers all characters that exist in all other character sets. UTF-8, in turn, can encode them all. Every character you get is encodable in UTF-8, no matter where it comes from. What I am actually thinking is that you are concerned about an encoding error somewhere else in the (HTTP?) protocol. If so, that may or may not be a valid concern, but if so it's a completely different question.